# How to use sampled_softmax_loss function in tensorflow's model_with_buckets?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow's model_with_buckets api function, there is a parameter named softmax_loss_function, the signature of which is Function (labels, logits) -> loss-batch.

```
def model_with_buckets(
    encoder_inputs,
    decoder_inputs,
    targets,
    weights,
    buckets,
    seq2seq,
    softmax_loss_function=None,
    per_example_loss=False,
    name=None
)
```

The traditional way of assigning softmax_loss_function is using anything like softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits:

```
def softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    _sentinel=None,
    labels=None,
    logits=None,
    dim=-1,
    name=None
)
```

While the sampled_softmax_loss function has following definition:

```
def sampled_softmax_loss(weights,
                     biases,
                     labels,
                     inputs,
                     num_sampled,
                     num_classes,
                     num_true=1,
                     sampled_values=None,
                     remove_accidental_hits=True,
                     partition_strategy="mod",
                     name="sampled_softmax_loss"):
```

In an official tensorflow seq2seq example about translate english to france, it assigned sampled_softmax_loss to model_with_bucket paramater with a wraper function sampled_loss as following:

```
w = tf.get_variable("proj_w", [size, self.target_vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32)
w_t = tf.transpose(w)
b = tf.get_variable("proj_b", [self.target_vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32)
output_projection = (w, b)

# maybe need Function (labels, logits)
def sampled_loss(labels, inputs):
        labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])
        return tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(w_t, b, inputs, labels, num_samples, self.target_vocab_size)

softmax_loss_function = sampled_loss
```

It's wield to me. And the code runs with a lot of errors. Because inputs is not equal logits. In my understanding, logits = inputs * weights + biases. So, what is the right way to use sampled_softmax_loss function in tensorflow's model_with_buckets?